# Is there software or online resources where I can measure double click time?

Tags: windows, mouse

The tool must run on Windows 10 and shall measure time between 2 clicks. Something [like this](http://unixpapa.com/js/testmouse.html); however I want to know exact ms between the double click.

How would I do so?

Comment: It must run on windows 10. I don't care what programming language it run. I do not think it requires a programmer. I am a programmer my self and can make such program easily. $5 price limit would be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use http://stopwatch.com/ and double click on the Start button, since it turns into a Stop button.